# Is there way to find a list of point coordinates where 3 or more lines touch eachother using shapely and geopandas in python?

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a Geopandas DataFrame with each row containing a shapely LineString. I need to find a list of points where three or more LineStrings touch each other. For example, in figure [Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFafp.png), I need the coordinates of the point where the three colored lines meet.

After I find all the points where three lines intersect, I need to merge the three lines to form two lines: 1) Pink + Purple 2) Green + Purple. The overlap should be fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have used a few countries for source of *LINESTRINGS*
- with this data set, there are only two points where there are three selected countries that intersect (as per visualisation)
- key concept is inner join points to points, then find points that have more than required number of repetitions

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# some polygons
# fmt: off
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).loc[lambda d: d["iso_a3"].isin(["BEL", "LUX", "NLD", "DEU", "AUT","POL"]), ["geometry", "iso_a3"]].reset_index(drop=True)
# fmt: on

# change to linestrings as per question
gdf["geometry"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(
    lambda p: shapely.geometry.LineString(p.exterior.coords)
)

# generate series of points from linestrings
points = (
    gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda l: l.coords).rename("point").explode().reset_index()
)

# 1. join all points to all points
# 2. exclude point to self
points = (
    points.merge(points, on=["point"])
    .drop_duplicates()
    .loc[lambda d: d["index_x"] != d["index_y"]]
)
# now find points that appera N times
n_times = (
    points.groupby(["point"])
    .size()
    .loc[lambda s: s >= 3]
    .reset_index()["point"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
)

# visualize to test...
px.scatter_mapbox(n_times, lon=0, lat=1, mapbox_style="carto-positron",).update_traces(
    marker_size=20
).update_layout(mapbox={"layers": [{"source": gdf.__geo_interface__, "type": "line"}]})
```

[image]